# How to run a method which belongs to various classe

Tags: java, methods, arguments

Good day to all experts,

First let me present my code:

```
public class CommonLogin {
public static void ComLogin(String TC, String address, String test_data, String common_data_tab, String TC_data_tab, String test_result ) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    String tc = TC;
    String url = address;
    String td = test_data;
    String cdt = common_data_tab;
    String tdt = TC_data_tab;
    String tr = test_result;
    String username;
    String password;
    String browser;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(td);      
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(cdt);
    System.out.println("No. of rows : " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
    for(int count = 1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++){
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
        System.out.println("Running Item no. " + row.getCell(0).toString());
        tc = row.getCell(0).toString();           
        username = row.getCell(1).toString();
        password = row.getCell(2).toString();       
        browser = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();            
        System.out.println(browser + " is calling");
        if(browser.contains("Firefox")){
            WebDriver login = new FirefoxDriver();          
            login.get(address);
            //login.get("https://2015.qa.int.www.mol.com/");
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lorem']/img")).isDisplayed();
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popupfoot']/a/i")).click();
            login.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();    
            Thread.sleep(2000);         
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='EmailAddress']")).sendKeys(username);
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys(password);        
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginForm']/footer[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/button")).click();        
            Thread.sleep(2000);  
            AcctDetailCaptchaFirefox.runTest(td,login);
        }
        else{
            WebDriver login = new ChromeDriver(); 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lam Chio Meng\\Desktop\\work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            login.get(address);
            //login.get("https://2015.qa.int.www.mol.com/");
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lorem']/img")).isDisplayed();//wait for Safety tips pop up to display
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popupfoot']/a/i")).click(); //click "X" to close popup
            login.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();    //click Log in
            Thread.sleep(2000);         
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='EmailAddress']")).sendKeys(username);
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys(password);        
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginForm']/footer[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/button")).click();    //cick on Login button    
            Thread.sleep(2000);   
            AcctDetailCaptchaChrome.runTest(td,login);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to draw your attention to the the syntax `if(browser.contains("Firefox")){` and proceed to the line `AcctDetailCaptchaChrome.runTest(td,login);` What this line simply does is send the arguments `td` and `login` to the method `runTest` in the class `AcctDetailCaptchaChrome`. However, now I got few other classes which also has the `runTest` method and the classes name are being passed via the `ComLogin`  method into the variable `tc` (refer the variable initialization part). So, now instead of `AcctDetailCaptchaChrome.runTest(td,login);`, I would like to have something like `tc.runTest(td,login)` where `tc` can be any class name being passed from main method.

Some advice on how to do this is deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you show some code from the `runTest` method? It would be useful to see what's going on in the `AcctDetailCaptchaChrome` class.

Comment: Assumig AcctDetailCaptchaChrome and AcctDetailCaptchaFirefox are inheriting from some super class (we'll call it AcctDetailCaptcha) which has the method runTest, you can get an argument of type AcctDetailCaptcha and call its runTest method.
This way it does not matter whether it is a AcctDetailCaptchaFirefox or AcctDetailCaptchaChrome or anything else

Comment: @px06, the code is too long to be published here. You can grab it from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4komPd_QXvgSDdlYzljVDRySjQ/view?usp=sharing. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Alon, Both the class are not inheriting from any superclass, ie, they are standalone and are the files with the main method. The reason of having these two classes is because each of them are a test case themself, and will be run when called upon. The idea is such that in `tc.runTest(), tc = either AcctDetailCaptchaChrome or AcctDetailCaptchaFirefox, and will intunr invoke the runTest method within them. Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: @lamCM Java is a type-safe language, which means that when defining a variable you define its type, this gives the advantage of not having errors when trying to call undefined methods and helps keeping track of variables, while it takes some freedom from the code and restricts you to use these types. Meaning you can't just create a variable and assign it different types. Inheritance is a way around that which also makes the code much more readable and safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use reflection. Here's a simple example to get you started.

```
 package test.oop;

 import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Reflection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Class xyClz = XY.class;
    Class zxClz = ZX.class;

    Method method = xyClz.getMethod("print", String.class);

    XY xy = new XY();
    method.invoke(xy, "greetings from xy");//this calls XY.print

    method = zxClz.getMethod("print", String.class);

    method.invoke(ZX.class, "greetings from zx");//this calls ZX.print
}

 }


   class XY{

public void print (String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
   }


   class ZX{

public static void print (String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
   }
```

The output is

```
  greetings from xy
  greetings from zx
```